# Multiplayer game for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, server-side

I am planning to make a multiplayer game for iOS. This will obviously require server side programming (which I have never done). I am going to start out with a simple turn based game just to learn. Can anyone suggest me which programming language/framework I should use and perhaps a tutorial/article for beginner specifically targeted toward server side programming for games?
Thanks.

Comment: hi, i need also same help.. B'coz i want also make one Checkers game in ios fro two player.. And also want to play with bluettoth.. So have you got any help ? Please tell me.. Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

I have used smartFox Server for creating a multiplayer game. You can test basic version for free. They have iPhone API and sample code too. checkitout http://www.smartfoxserver.com/

Comment: i second that. it takes a while to get used to, but the docs are getting better and better, and they fixed a couple of weirdnesses in the SFS2X release.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the language you have a couple of options. If I were you I would go with:

- PHP; lots of tutorials and information can be found on the internet
- Google AppEngine; their python bindings are really good and it's pretty much made for what you're describing.